# How are fluorochromes conjugated to proteins such as antibody?

Tags: immunology, biochemistry

How are fluorochromes like FITC conjugated to antibodies? Are they covalently bonded? If they are covalently bonded, will low temperature (-20 Celsius or lower) break the covalent bonds and detach the fluorochrome label from the protein?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluorochromes are covalently bound to the antibodies to form stably labelled molecules. This [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20012817) describes it in great detail, from the abstract:

> Fluorochromes can be covalently conjugated to antibodies through
>   reactions with thiol or amine groups. Typically, fluorochromes
>   containing isothiocyanate, succinimidyl ester, or sulfonyl chloride
>   reactive groups are conjugated to amines on the antibody molecules.

These covalent bonds are stable at room temperature and are also at -20°C. It's more likely that repeated freeze-thaw cycles damage the antibody.

Comment: most of the direct-conjugated antibodies for cytometric analysis I've purchased usually specifically point out "Do not freeze". I am recently staining FITC labeled peanut agglutinin for B220+ B cells. The labeled PNA was stored in 4C but when I took it out, it was in frozen form. I've tried dilutions to 1:1000 but there doesn't seem to have enough negative population compared to negative control. Almost all stained populations displayed fluorescent intensity over 10^2. I was worried if the freezing caused the fluorochrome to detach from the PNA protein.

Comment: @AlexB I think it is more the repeated freeze-thaw cycles which are problematic for the antibody. The labelling is pretty stable as far as I know.

Comment: @AlexB is the FITC-PNA in DMSO or aqueous solution? If it's DMSO, it'll freeze at 4°.